# I want to know how to draw class diagram in this case

Tags: java, class, uml

I use java swing GUI and
This is my class

**`Home(UserList Userlist, BookList BookList);`**

**`BooK(UserList userList,BookList bookList);`**

In class "Home", when user click button then `new Book(userList,bookList);`

The class "Book" is the class which extends the JFrame

The class "Book" only created when click the button in "Home" class(make new window)

UserList and BookList is the class which handle some arraylist.(db of my program, i want to send userList and bookList data from home class to book class)

And i want to draw class diagram between Home and Book....is it **Composition or Association?**

And how about userList, bookList between Home, Book? Home and Book didn't create object userList, bookList. only get parameter. is it Association?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Respecting *stricto sensu* your list of classes.

> ```
> Home(UserList Userlist, BookList BookList);
> BooK(UserList userList,BookList bookList);
> ```
>
> In class "Home", when user click button then `new Book(userList,bookList);`

the constructor of *Home* receives in argument a *UserList* and a *BookList*, supposing the handler of the click is supported by one of the operations of *Home*, the class *Home* needs to memorize them. Supposing these lists and the instances they contain exist independently of the class *Home* which does not clone them, these lists are memorized through a simple association, not a composition.

> And i want to draw class diagram between Home and Book....is it Composition or Association?

None of them, in the description you give *Home* does not need to have a (direct) association nor a composition to *Book*, the association with *BookList* is enough.

If you want you can have a dependency stereotyped *create* between *Home* and *Book* to indicate *Home* creates *Book*(s).

> And how about userList, bookList between Home, Book? Home and Book didn't create object userList, bookList. only get parameter. is it Association?

No. To receive a *UserList* and a *BookList* in argument in a constructor or an other operation does not means you have association to them.

If I put all in a diagram :

[image]

---

Having the composition `ClassA <*>----> ClassB` means when an instance of *ClassA* disappears the corresponding instance of *ClassB* disappears too.

Having the association `ClassA ----> ClassB` or even the aggregation `ClassA <>----> ClassB`, when an instance of *ClassA* disappears the corresponding instance of *ClassB* may survive.

Answer (score 0):

It depends if each Home as a lot of books ( an array of books ) so it's an aggregation between Home and Book.
For BookList and UserList if those can be counted as attributes of Home class or Book class than it s an association, otherwise there is no relation between them